# Language server creation in Monaco Editor

Tags: languageservice, monaco-editor

I have gone through the docs and found out that in order to provide diagnostics for a custom language in Monaco editor, we need to write our own language server/client. In example [1], it is written in Typescript. Can we write the server in Javascript itself?

[1] https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-languageserver-node-example/tree/master/client

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is years old, but in the interest of anyone else who stumbles by... Typescript *is* fully backwards compatible to JavaScript. Because of this, any valid JavaScript is in fact, valid Typescript.

So, anything that needs to be written in Typescript can in fact be written in JavaScript.